# "my sister, my bride". Isn't that incestuous?

Tags: song-of-songs, bride

Song of Solomon 4:9
You have stolen my heart, my sister, my bride; you have stolen my heart with one glance of your eyes, with one jewel of your necklace.

Is this supposed to sound romantic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even today, one might be a 'brother' to a 'sister' in a church congregation. And then marry the sister, making her a spouse.

The spirituality of the Song of Solomon exceeds natural relationships and transcends the limitations of them, to express what is true of Christ and the Bride of Christ.

No, it should not be read as 'romantic'. It is setting forth spiritual truth and spiritual experience.

As with much of the Hebrew scripture, the full revelation is only understood in the light of the full revelation of the New Testament writings. Thus the Song of Solomon will not be fully perceived without the understanding of what is revealed of Jesus Christ in the apostolic scriptures.

Comment: I downvoted because this idea that the Song of Songs shouldn't be read as romantic or erotic is just silly to any common sense reading of the text. We can spiritualize and ascribe additional meaning that the author may not have had in mind in light of history and later revelation. But this idea that the plain romantic meaning of the Song of Songs  should be dismissed is just bad hermeneutics.

Answer (score 3):

The names that the two lovers have for each other are many in the famous love poem of the Song of Songs, such as:

- "My beloved", SS 1:13, 2:8, 5:16
- "My darling", SS 1:9, 15, 4:1, 6:4
- "My friend", SS 5:16.
- "My bride", SS 4:9
- "My dove", SS 2:16
- "My sister", SS 4:9
- Most beautiful", SS 5:9, 6:1
- "Prince's daughter", SS 7:1
- "gazelle", "stag", SS 8:14

... and so forth.  These are all wonderful pet names of deep affection as they express their strong love for each other, and the closeness of their bond.

Answer (score 3):

Since I was asked to put my comment into an answer/post, I will do so:

Nothing to do with incest, but it is about sublimity of romantic love, when love is sublimated and refined, and “sister” is a symbol-word of this sublimity. Similarly, in another inspired text of roughly the same period, Homer’s “Iliad”, Andromache says to her husband Hector: “Hector, thou art to me father and queenly mother, thou art brother, and thou art my stalwart husband”. If romantic love does not tend to a sublimation towards brotherhood-sistership, such romantic love will descend into crude lust and pornography.

Just imagine Pierre Abellard - after having been castrated by his beloved Eloise's jealous father, and having become a monk and Eloise a nun, with a sublime philosophical correspondence ensuing between them - was miraculously operated and given his cut member back, and he and Eloise impatiently and joyfully engaging themselves in a wild romantic sex immediately after that, as if all they dreamt about was that. But it would have been laughable and they of course would have continued the same sublime and chaste correspondence, not because sex is any sin, but because *volens nolens* they reached a sublimity that does not require any more sex but transcends it and is more desirable than sex. As Alexander Pope describes their condition:

How happy is the blameless vestal's lot!

The world forgetting, by the world forgot.

Eternal sunshine of the spotless mind!

Each pray'r accepted, and each wish resign'd;

Tears that delight, and sighs that waft to Heav'n.

Grace shines around her with serenest beams" etc.

Of course, if barrel of a gun is put to Abelard's and Eloise's temples and they are forced to have sex with each other, they perhaps would do, but not voluntarily, for voluntarily they smacked already more finesse tastes and pleasures than those promised by sex.

Thus, not only their, but any romantic love has a logic of sublimating into a purer and purer forms, which can be symbolically called also "brotherhood-sistership", and unless it does so, there is no stagnation, but either ascent or degradation, and, so, such non-ascending romantic love will degrade into animality.

Not only Bible says so, but entire experience of humanity expressed in great pieces of world literature of all ages.